# ASP.NET C# - Multiple MySQL transactions

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, transactions, ado.net

I have the following MySQL tables:

```
tests:
test_id (PK, AI), author_id (FK), module_id (FK), name

questions:
question_id (PK, AI), module_id (FK), author_id (FK), approved, question, type

answers:
answer_id (PK, AI), question_id (FK), answer, correct

tests_questions:
id (PK, AI), test_id (FK), question_id (FK)
```

I'm trying to implement a facility whereby a user can create a test that has *n* number of questions (depending on a DropDownList value).  Each question has one or more answers.

So far, I've got a page (create_test.aspx) for the user to enter the test details + select the number of questions.

I intend to have a Button_Click event whereby the user is redirected to another page (create_test2.aspx) to enter the details for Question 1 + linked answers.  On the same page, within a Button_Click event, this is repeated for the *n* number of questions.

However, I'm not sure when exactly I should write to the database and if I should store all the details somehow and write all the data at the end.  Any help please?

I could insert a row in the 'tests' table on the initial page's Button_Click event and then insert each question/answers on each subsequent Button_Click event, however, what happens if the user leaves the page halfway through entering the questions?  So I imagine this is not a sensible option?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a perfect use case for a stored procedure in sql

Comment: I'm not familiar with stored procedures but I'll check them out.  Should I temporarily store the data entered on create_test.aspx or write to the database?